# Mathematical Physics: Does it Belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Does mathematical physics questions belong here, or on math?

Say, for example, I wish to ask about [Penrose–Hawking singularity theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems)-- basically they are just the theorems and the solutions of Einstein gravitational field equations. Or I wish to ask about the existence and smoothness of navier-stokes equation ( talking about [clay institutes's millennium prize problem](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Navier-Stokes_Equations/navierstokes.pdf)). Should I post the question here, or on Math SE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the question requires any physical insight/understanding, then you are best off posting it here I think. It is more appropriate and you will probably get higher quality answers.

If, however, the question is purely relating to manipulating and solving complex equations that happen to *appear* in physics, then Math StackExchange (or MathOverflow even) may be the better place.

Comment: Note: there's sometimes a fine line, in which case trying both sites may be acceptable...

Answer (score 2):

I think it would mostly depend on the field of the person asking the question. If it is a physics student they may want a more "physics-y" answer. If it is a math student maybe they want the insight of the Physics.SE community. Essentially, it should be asked wherever the OP decides to ask it. Maybe someone could suggest they try their hand at asking on MSE or MO if they are of the opinion they would get a better answer there. In general, I think each separate community will provide different insight, so why not allow it?